# TypeOrm Entity and ormconfigs

Tags: typescript, typeorm

Hello I'm in doubt about the typem ormconfig
I have a dockerfile with the following 
**setup:**

```
#building code
FROM node as builder
WORKDIR usr/app
COPY package*.json ./
RUN yarn install
COPY . .
RUN yarn run build

#stage 2
FROM node
WORKDIR usr/app
COPY package*.json ./
RUN yarn install --production

COPY --from=builder /usr/app/dist ./dist

COPY ormconfig.json .
COPY .env . 

expose 4000
CMD node dist/src/index.js
```

my orm config is this:

```
{
  "type": "postgres",
  "host": "db",
  "port": 5432,
  "username": "spirit",
  "password": "emasa",
  "database": "emasa_base",
  "synchronize": true,
  "logging": false,
  "entities": ["src/entity/**/*.ts"],
  "migrations": ["src/migration/**/*.ts"],
  "subscribers": ["src/subscriber/**/*.ts"],
  "cli": {
    "entitiesDir": "src/entity",
    "migrationsDir": "src/migration",
    "subscribersDir": "src/subscriber"
  }
}
```

But as I am with typescript and using a docker to run my node I am in doubt what I should put in:

```
"entities": ["src / entity / ** / *. ts"],
      "migrations": ["src / migration / ** / *. ts"],
      "subscribers": ["src / subscriber / ** / *. ts"]
```

src or dist?

at the moment src is not creating my tables in the database when starting the server I don't know why

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when you compile ts code to js, the file extension will be change from `.ts` to `.js`, then you have to change your `ormconfig`

Example:

```
"entities": ["src/entity/**/*.ts"],
```

to

```
"entities": ["src/entity/**/*.js"], // Or dist/src/entity/**/*.js
```

Answer (score 0):

This way is more generic and you can refer to it with both extensions:

```
"entities": [`src/entity/**/*{.ts,.js}`]
```